# VBA point variable to range

Tags: vba, object, range

I want to point to a cell as a range in VBA. I've tried using:

```
         Dim range
         range = Sheet("sheet").Range("A1")
```

But this just returns the value in the range. What I actually want is the range object so I can manipulate it, e.g. by setting range.Value = "Hello"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

First, I strongly recommend you to make explicit declaration of variables in your code mandatory. Go to *Tools - Options*, in the *Editor* tab check *"Require variable Declaration"*, or put `Option Explicit` in the first line of all your scripts.

Second, I think there is a small typo in your code, it should be `Sheets.("sheet")`.

To answer your question, with `range = Sheets("sheet").Range("A1")` you are assigning a value variable, not an object. Therefore the default variable of the range object is implicitly assigned, which is `value`. In order to assign an object, use the `Set` keyword. My full example code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim RangeObject As range
    Set RangeObject = Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1")    
    RangeObject.Value = "MyTestString"
End Sub
```

This should put the text "MyTestString" in cell A1.

**Edit:** If you are using named ranges, try `RangeObject.Value2` instead of `RangeObject.Value`. Named ranges do not have a `Value` property.

Comment: Using "Require Variable Declaration" will not retrospectively affect any existing modules - it just controls whether Excel will automatically put Option Explicit at the top of any *new* modules. So, even if you set this option on, you'll still have to go through any existing modules and add Option Explicit.

Comment: If have a number of named ranges, lets call them "Name1", "Name2" and "Name3" I want to access them like this: Set nameRange= range("Name" & Number) and do the following: If nameRange.Value <> someValue Then nameRange.Value = someValue - This fails though!